# Null Values in Date Column

Tags: sql, parameters, oracle11g

I have a table that has the following data:

```
ITEM   LOCATION   RECEIVE_DATE
001     13001     27-JAN-2016
002     14001       null
```

I am using the following to retrieve the results in two parameters:

```
select * from item_master
where 
(TRUNC (RECEIVE_DATE) between NVL(:STARTDATE, TRUNC(RECEIVE_DATE)) and NVL(:enddate, trunc(RECEIVE_DATE)));
```

If I input both the date parameters as null, I only get the records that have RECEIVE_DATE and excludes all the records with null RECEIVE_DATE

How should I retrieve all the rows if I do not enter any value for the parameter?

Answer (score 2):

You could add `OR` and `IS NULL`:

```
select * 
from item_master
where 
  (TRUNC(RECEIVE_DATE) 
  between NVL(:STARTDATE, TRUNC(RECEIVE_DATE)) and NVL(:enddate, trunc(RECEIVE_DATE)))
  OR (:STARTDATE IS NULL AND :enddate IS NULL);
```